# Odoo How to add custom field to crm.lead

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

Hi dear I'm trying to add custom field to crm.lead

```
   class Lead(models.Model):
      _inherits = 'crm.lead'

      x_facturation = fields.Boolean("x_facturation", default=False)


<record model="ir.ui.view" id="devis_form_view">
    <field name="name">lead.facturation</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <notebook position="inside">
            <page string="Factures">
                <group>
                      <field name="x_facturation"/>                         
                </group>
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </field>
</record>
```

But I got error while installing : Field x_facturation does not exist
When I try with else model (ex : res.partner) it work fine

Answer (score 0):

**In this case if you want to add the field on view so that you have to do the following things :**

**1. Inherit the class (model) and add that field into you model**

(In your case you want to add your field in crm.lead class so we will have to add your favorite field on it )

**2. Add that field into the Odoo (OpenERP) view like List view (tree view),form view etc..**

(In your case you want to add your field in crm.lead form view or any other view so that we must have to inherit it in our module)

The field will be added into the view based on xpath using position attribute.

Above all the things are working fine then you must have upgrade your module properly and restart the OpenERP server and then after you can check the effect.
because in your case it might not yet doing this job.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Sir, I am adding some custom fields in `crm.lead`. fields are successfully added but when i refresh form fields are going disappear, and whan again i on debug mode, than fields again appearing ... it is happening in odoo 9.

Comment: Have you tried to use the latest Odoo 9.0 devalopment source ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using _inherit instead of _inherits and update the database with the module.

Try using _inherit instead of _inherits and update the database with the module.